# Chrome won't access http://0.0.0.0:4200/

Tags: google-chrome

I'm developing an ember-application which is hosted locally on `http://0.0.0.0:4200/` .
Via Safari I can access the URL without any problems but Chrome always searches for it up on Google.

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the URL with `http://` in front?

Comment: looks like a known issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428046 and the status is "wont-fix" which isnt encouraging :(

Comment: just a tought http://127.0.0.1:4200/ ?

Comment: Encountered this today on the 0.0.0.0:4200 --- The 127.0.0.1:4200 is working for me. I hadn't cracked open ember in a few weeks... but I thought it used to always prompt with this number... ?

Answer (score 20):

#### Chrome won't access http://0.0.0.0:4200/

This is because `0.0.0.0` is not a routable IP address and is never used as a destination address.

---

> In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a
>   **non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non
>   applicable target**.

Source [0.0.0.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

---

> **0.0.0.0**    “Me”: (Alternately, “this host”, or “the current/default host”). **Used by a device to refer to itself when it doesn't know its
>   own IP address**. The most common use is when a device attempts to
>   determine its address using a host-configuration protocol like DHCP.
>   May also be used to indicate that any address of a multihomed host may
>   be used.

Source [IP Addresses With Special Meanings](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPAddressesWithSpecialMeanings-2.htm)

---

> The address 0.0.0.0 may only be used as the address of an outgoing
>   packet when  a computer is learning which IP address it should use. 
>   **It is never used as a destination address.**

Source [IP Information for 0.0.0.0](http://whois.domaintools.com/0.0.0.0)

---

#### Further reading

- [Is 0.0.0.0 a valid IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address)

Comment: tl;dr; use http://localhost:4200

Comment: Also, if it is listening on "0.0.0.0" means it is accessible on all your interfaces. You may want to restrict it to local access by making it listen only on loopback (e.g. 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple trick:
Go to the hosts file (it depends on which OS you have) and add a record:

> 0.0.0.0       whatever.youlike

Now open chrome and goto `whatever.youlike` and it works.

For Windows:

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

For Mac:

`/private/etc/hosts`

For Linux:

`/etc/hosts`

Answer (score -1):

Another way you can get it to open it is to run `open http://0.0.0.0:port`, which, although easy, tells us that chrome only opens it if the OS forces it to.

Answer (score -2):

It's a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428046). After several arguments, they decided that are going to fix it.

Comment: The link appears to be a bunch of people complaining about the same problem rather than a definitive source documenting that it is a bug.